# linked list - searching node by value

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

its a self sorted node when i search the node by search(int x) function the program stops if the x > then the greatest node value ie last node value
following is the program

```
   void search(int value)
      {
    if(!isEmpty())
    {

        loc = start;
        pedloc = NULL;
        int n=1;
        while(loc != NULL && loc->data < value)
        {
             pedloc= loc;
            loc = loc->next;
        n++;
        }

        if(loc != NULL && loc->data != value)
        {
            loc = NULL;
            cout<<"value not exist"<<endl;
            return;
        }

        cout<<"value "<<loc->data<<" is present at #" 
      <<n<<" node"<<endl;
    }

  }
```

Comment: There's something very important that's missing from your question. That would be an actual question.

Comment: you can do it within one loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the ways you can identify the node by the value.

```
void search(int value)
    {
        node *temp=new node;
        temp=head;
        int pos = 1;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp->data == value)
            {
                cout << "" << value << " is at position: " << pos << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (temp->next == NULL && temp->data != value)
            {
                cout << "" << value << " is not part of the linked list" << endl;
                break;
            }
            temp=temp->next;
            pos++;
        }
    }
```

This sample code kind of matches with what you want to achieve. It is easier to find the node by the value while inside the loop. When the node is found, just break the loop. If we are at the last node and the value does not exist that means the value and subsequently the node is not part of the linked list which is what the "else if" condition is checking.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, while loop will be terminated in two cases, 
if `loc==null or loc->data >= value`. In both these cases, your search input is not found in given list.

hence `loc==null` or `loc->data >= value` should be added in your if check.